# T-SQL- calculate rota patterns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

I'm using SQL 2012. 
I have a database table populated with personnel data. Every individual has a Start Date (`1/1/1990`, `24/11/2004`, `3/4/2018` etc).

Every individual has a rota of a set length which starts on their respective start date.

The pattern rolls for its length E.g. 7, 14, 21 days before reoccurring and is governed by Contract Length

Fields:

[image]

If you had a length '4' and on day 2 you are fully available the database will show your contract as day 0 start end, day 1 start end, day 3 start end because the way the database records data, it only tells you when you aren't available and you must infer that you are available

We're looking to create a script so that based on someone's start date and pattern, we can determine what day of the rota they are on at [user defined date].

Comment: Could you please add a table representing your desired output?  It is not entirely clear from your explanation what you are after here.

Comment: DATEDIFF(day, [Start Date], @UserDefinedDate) % [Length of Pattern] + 1  --would give you day 1,2,3,4 ...... Length of Pattern.  % is mod, or modular arithmetic value, so it will cycle round and round as days difference from start date increases

Comment: You'll want to split up the ContractDaysRange field into two columns for ContractDaysMin and ContractDaysMax.

Comment: @iamdave The desired output is an additional column which determines as of the current date which day of the rota pattern an individual is currently on.

Comment: @pseudonym  It is all well and good you saying that, but for those of us who are not familiar with your environment and data source, providing us with the original data tables (I do not think the picture in your question is your actual source table) and an exact output that we can check our solutions against is very helpful.  Doing this will make the volunteers here much more inclined to give their time to help you.